# Toggling off verbosity in the find command

Tags: shell, find, command

I'm trying to toggle off the verbosity of the find command while writing the results to a text file and sending the process to the background.

I'm using this command:

```
find / -ctime 7 1> /home/user1/Changed_Last7Days.txt &
```

Tried to redirect the error-free output (used 1> according to POSIX) but it still printing out the errors in the terminal session.

I don't understand how or if I can combine /dev/null/ redirection with this one liner.

I tried to be as clear as I can.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1>` only redirects file descriptor number 1, standard output. It doesn't change where the errors go. (`1>file` is same as just `>file`)  To get rid of any errors, add another redirection to send them  to `/dev/null`. They are written to file descriptor 2.

```
find / -ctime 7 1> /home/user1/Changed_Last7Days.txt  2>/dev/null &
```

Or, if you wanted to redirect both stdout and stderr to the same place, use:

```
find / -ctime 7 1> /home/user1/Changed_Last7Days.txt  2>&1 &
```